# Group actions - modulo 4

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, group-actions

I am having a bit trouble understanding group actions. if I am given a set A = {a,b,c,d} and a group action s: Z mod 4 -> $S_A$, how would one then be able to show if there exists a group action s such that s(2) = (a b). The only thing I seem to be able to get out of this information is that: 
$s(f +_4 g) = s_f \circ s_g $ and $s(e) = e_A$. But I don't know if that is useful in any way.

Comment: Isn't the axioms the 2 ones that I have written in the question?

Comment: Axiom $2$ is compatibility: $(gh).x = g.(h.x)$ for all $g, h \in G$ and all $x\in X$ - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action).

Comment: I think that it is the same just in the alternate definition.

Comment: What is $S_A$ ?

Comment: the set of permutations of A :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Look at the image of $1$ mod $4$ through $s$.

The order of $s(1)$ may be $1$, $2$ or $4$. If the image  $s(1)$ is of order $1$ or $2$ then $s(2)=s(1)^2$...

If the image  $s(1)$ is of order $4$ then it is a $4$-cycle, $s(2)$ will be the square of a $4$-cycle... can it happen that this gives a transposition ?

Comment: I know that the order of s(1) is 4 - what do you mean with transposition? :)

Comment: Okay I see what a transposition is, but how would one get from this to s(2) = (a b)  ?, because I don't really get what s(1) is :)

Comment: The order of $s(1)$ needs to divide the order of $1$ in $Z$ mod $4$ (which is $4$). A transposition is an element of the form $(i,j)\in S_n$ it exchanges $i$ and $j$ and leaves everything else fixed.

Comment: My point is that $s(2)$ can never be a transposition... $s(1)$ is the image of $1$ by $s$, hence it is a brave element of $S_A$.